# How to enable SSL3 and disable SSL2 via putty?

Tags: linux, ssl, putty

Can anybody give me some reference or steps for how we can disable the SSL2 and enable SSL3 for linux machine via putty. I am totally unaware of it. So need help..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty uses SSH not SSL. Thus disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 is not possible because they are not in use.

Comment: we need to disable the SSL2 and enable SSL3 on linux machine using putty. please correct me if i am wrong -> we are using putty for access the server. so does it matters what putty uses?

Comment: @lakhan It doesn't even matter that you're using `putty` *at all.* What you need to discover is the *command line* or *configuration file that you need to edit*. How you get to that point is entirely irrelevant. And the question not being a programming question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @EJP OK..!! yes the thing i need the solution for this that how can i configure this..!! This is only the solution for me :)

Comment: I have something about it...that i guess i need to edit the "httpd.conf" file for that...but still i am not sure about this...so need help for this..!!!

Comment: @DLV: if you need to know how to disable SSLv2, SSLv3 you first need to know which software is affected (web server, mail server ...?) and then look at the documentation of the software. This has absolutely nothing to do with how you access the server itself. And for questions about sever configuration see serverfault.com or superuser.com.